# Azure Diagnostic Settings created by Terraform is causing 'Resource already exists' error when re-applying the same Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Using Terrafrom I am deploying AKS cluster, Vnet and KeyVaults. For all the resources, I am enabling the 'azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting' with the name of resource with name                       = "DiagnosticsSettings". Once the first time deployment is completed by Terraform, If I reapply the terraform by making configuration changes to few resources, I am only getting the error for 'azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting' stating that '**Resource Already Exists**', even though there is no change made for the 'azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting'.

Below is my Terraform code:

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "settings" {
  count                      = var.log_analytics_enabled ? 1:0 
  name                       = "DiagnosticsSettings"
  target_resource_id         = azurerm_application_gateway.network.id
  log_analytics_workspace_id = var.log_analytics_workspace_id

  enabled_log   {
    category = "ApplicationGatewayAccessLog"

    retention_policy {
      enabled = true
      days    = var.log_analytics_retention_days
    }
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Error: creating Monitor Diagnostics Setting "DiagnosticsSettings-UAT-HubVNet" for Resource "/subscriptions/ce8fa7fa83bd/resourceGroups/env-UAT-RG/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/UAT-HubVNet": diagnosticsettings.DiagnosticSettingsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=409 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=<nil> <nil>
│ 
│   with module.hub_network.azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting.settings[0],
│   on ..\modules\virtual_network\main.tf line 36, in resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "settings":
│   36: resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "settings" {
```

I see my option to resolve this issue is to do the 'terraform import', but how can I write import command for resource which I dont know will error-out. Or I cant write import for all the resources. How to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

I initially created azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting for the keyvault .
When the same resource with but with different identifier is set with same settings and parameters, already exits error occurs

```
 resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "exampleone" {
  name               = "example"
  target_resource_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.stdg.id
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example.id

  enabled_log {
    category = "AuditEvent"

    retention_policy {
      enabled = false
    }
  }

  metric {
    category = "AllMetrics"

    retention_policy {
      enabled = false
    }
  }
}
```

Here example > changed to exampleonen ,resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "exampleone" ,   but the  settings remains same , i.e; new diagnostic setting is created with same name but using  other identifier terraform

[image]

In your code when count =2 , two resources will be created , for index “0”, and index ”1” but both the resources have same name      ="DiagnosticsSettings" , so when one resource with is created and then the other starts to create with the same name and settings, the error already exists occurs.

Its giving error,

**Error:**

```
     creating Monitor Diagnostics Setting "examples-1" for Resource "/subscriptions/xxx16/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/expdgkeyvault": diagnosticsettings.DiagnosticSettingsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=409 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=<nil> <nil>
│
```

[image]

So make sure the setting has different name with different targetIds.

Here creating two diagnostic settings with same target is not the right way.That is a conflicting operation and terraform import doesn’t work.

So the name can be changed this way according to count.

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "exampleee" {
  count = 2
  name               = "exampleka-${count.index}"
  target_resource_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  storage_account_id = azurerm_storage_account.stdg.id
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example.id

  enabled_log {
    category = "AuditEvent"
    retention_policy {
      enabled = false
    }
  }

  metric {
    category = "AllMetrics"

    retention_policy {
      enabled = false
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

But the diagnostic settings conflict with same target.

[image]

> **Note: The 409 conflict is expected behaviour when there is already on going operation and when you tried to perform another operation on
> the same while the previous operation is not completed.**